# How to enable concurrent Http2 connections in Grpc.Core?

Tags: c#, grpc

`Grpc.Net.Client` library [allows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/performance?view=aspnetcore-7.0#connection-concurrency) to enable concurrent Http2 connections.

Is there a similar setting for `Grpc.Core` core library?